# Why can't I use polymorphism in j2me?

Tags: java, java-me, lwuit

I'm using LWUIT as my j2me project's GUI library. I've generated a netbeans project using LWUIT Resource editor. And I have a separate project, in which I write additional components for my j2me program.

In that separate project, I have a class `TextForm extends Form`, where Form is a standard LWUIT's form. When I try to do:

```
TextForm a = new TextForm();
a.show();
```

everything's works fine. But when I do:

```
Form a = new TextForm();
a.show();
```

I have a compile-time error:

```
Error preverifying class userclasses.StateMachine
    VERIFIER ERROR userclasses/StateMachine.onConnect()V:
Cannot find class client/lwuit/components/TextForm
```

(the TextForm class contains in the `client.lwuit.components` package of my separate project with components). So, is there any solution for this problem?

UPD:
a.show() method is a standard Form method. It is responsible for displaying forms. It's not so important here.

Comment: It looks like the assignment itself is valid, but what happened to the `TextForm` class?

Comment: are you sure this isn't a human error (project misconfiguration ...)?

Comment: I haven't done any changes in my project's configuration (accept importing of this additional project with TextForm).

Answer (score 1):

For anyone, who cares: the error was in the project's build-impl.xml file (it's location is /nbproject/build-impl.xml). It's generated incorrectly. The error is in the line

```
<nb-preverify srcdir="${preverify.sources.dir}" destdir="${preverify.classes.dir}" classpath="${platform.bootclasspath}:${extra.classpath}" configuration="${platform.configuration}" platformhome="${platform.home}" platformtype="${platform.type}" commandline="${platform.preverifycommandline}"/>
```

Look at this tag's attribute named classpath:

```
classpath="${platform.bootclasspath}:${extra.classpath}"
```

In order to tell the preverifyer where your included libraries are, change this attribute to the following form:

```
classpath="${platform.bootclasspath}:${extra.classpath}:${libs.classpath}"
```

If you look into the `project.properties` file (it is in the same directory as the build-impl.xml), you can see, that `libs.classpath` variable provides a path to all your project's libs, that you include.

P.S.: yes, it seems pretty weird, that this affects polymorphism in such way, but it solved the problem...

Comment: If you solved your own problem then you should mark this as the answer! Or just delete the question altogether if you think it is unlikely to help anyone else.

Comment: The system says, that I'll be able to mark this as the answer only in 14 hours.